# Data not loaded properly from csv file to hive table

Tags: hive, hiveql

Hi I am new to stackoverflow.
I want to load a csv file to into a hive table.
I have created hive table using:

```
 create table database1.table1(......) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Also I have loaded the data into the table using:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH .... OVERWRITE INTO TABLE database1.table1;
```

But when I run this:

```
select distinct col1 from table1;
```

I am getting values from other columns along with values from **col1**.

According to me the the data has not been loaded properly (i.e column wise) in the hive table.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please share your sample csv data?Are you trying to load data from local or hdfs?

Comment: @KZapagol Here is the csv: https://drive.google.com/open?id=15U4n-g5xjG2uCMs3lHUtvvFdDHr_ffhJ

Comment: @KZapagol I am loading it from HDFS. Although I can do it from Linux FS(local) also but haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this by doing a `cat` of the the file that belongs to this table in HDFS and see if the value for the column is missing for any records.

```
hdfs dfs -cat <hdfs_path/file>
```

You can get this HDFS path if you do not know it by running the below query in Hive.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE database1.table1;
```

Look for the word LOCATION in the result of above query and you can get the HDFS path.

Tip: You can get the file to your local and load the data in an excel sheet with comma as delimiter and see if you see any missing values for any rows.

To get the File from HDFS to local: `hdfs dfs -get <HDFS_Path> <local_path>`

Answer (score 0):

You are right, data has not been loaded properly (i.e column wise) in the hive table. You are getting values from other columns along with values from col1 which means entire row values are stored/loaded into in column 1.

Complete statement used to create table is not given in question. So I used following DDL statement to create table.

```
create table table1 (
date_received string,
Product varchar(100),
Sub_product string,
Issue string,
Sub_issue string,
Consumer_complaint_narrative string,
Company_public_response string,
Company string,
State string,
ZIP_code string,
Tags string,
Consumer_consent_provided string,
Submitted_via string,
Date_sent_to_company string,
Company_response_to_consumer string,
Timely_response varchar(3),
Consumer_disputed string,
Complaint_ID bigint
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
with SERDEPROPERTIES ( "separatorChar"=",","skip.header.line.count"="1")
stored as textfile;
```

Used following statement to load data

```
load data inpath '/user/test/Complaints2months.csv' into table table1;
```

Validated this in my local and is loading data properly. Hope this will solve your problem.

**Notes:**

1. "separatorChar"="," - Default separator char is ',' so this property
   is not mandatory in this case.
2. Instead of SERDE class you can also use *ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','*
3. Also table is stored in TEXTFILE format. This is due to the format of input file. 'load data' command does not do any transformations on data.